# Do while loop in property causes stack

Tags: c#, exception, null

I've recently started trying to teach myself C# and this is very much a beginner's attempt at the implementation of using business rules in a property, in my case the FurColor.  When I run the program below I get a `NullReferenceException`.  Can someone help me find the cause of this error?  The exception occurs at **line 15**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _10_23_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("programming practice!");
            Dog d = new Dog();
            Console.Write("what color is your dog: ");
            d.FurColor = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("the color of your dog is {0}", d.FurColor);
        }
    }
    class Dog
    {
        private string furColor;
        private string petName;
        private int tagNum;

        public Dog() { }

        public Dog(string color, string name, int tagID)
        {
            furColor = color;
            petName = name;
            tagNum = tagID;
        }
        //properties
        public string FurColor
        {
            get { return furColor; }
            set {                    
                    do
                    {
                        Console.Write("enter in a viable color type: ");
                    }
                    while (furColor.Length > 10);
                    furColor = value;
                }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return petName; }
            set { petName = value; }
        }
        public int TagNum
        {
            get { return tagNum; }
            set { tagNum = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what line do you get the exception?

Comment: you aren't assigning anything in your loop in `FurColor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once corrected you will get an infinite loop though.

Side note : You should not ask for input in the Set clause of your property.

You should prefer a member function that would ask for the input, check if it's valid and then set the color.

In you dog class add a function that looks like this :

```
public void setFurColor()
{
    string color = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("what color is your dog: ");
        color = Console.ReadLine();
    }while ( ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(color)  && bleh.Length < 10);
    this.furColor = color;
}
```

Comment: i'll keep this in mind.  thanks.  this was just popped into my head with my made up scenario.

Comment: The main problem was that you had no mechanism to reassign the value in your loop, so this would have generated an infinite loop.

Comment: I was under the impression that one shouldn't use getter or setter methods, rather use properties.  should getter and setter methods be used if there is simple business logic and not automatic properties?

Comment: It depends of the context. In your example you were asking inputs from the user in order to set the value, this logic should not be part of the property because it would create a problem when you want to reuse the object in a different context.

Comment: interesting.  thanks, i'll keep these things in mind as i learn.

Answer (score 1):

Check **furColor** against null before accessing its `furColor.Length`

Answer (score 1):

You code doesn't make any sense, but it's ok since you are learning how to code. :)

So - I guess that you want to store furColor ONLY if user entered string that is GREATER in length than 10 characters.  If that is so, you should check if the string is OK before you assign the value to an object property, and if not, loop with a warning message OUTSIDE of the class property code.

Comment: when i'm reading a reference book and looking and their programs it makes all the sense in the world.  when i'm trying to put something together on my own without looking at anything...that's a different story

Comment: Well, that feels that way in the beginning.  It will settle once you try and fail about 100 times :)

Answer (score 1):

To make the code that you have work: You're accessing `furColor.Length` without ever setting furcolor...at that point it's nothing (null). you should be checking `value`.

Additionally, this isn't the kind of logic you want in a setter on a property. Your setter shouldn't be outputting an reading values, it should simply set the property as that's what it's for. Put the while loop in your main.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the public parameterless constructor of Dog

```
public Dog() { }
```

This constructor doesn't set the `furColor` field, so it will be null in your `Dog` instance.

This means that accessing the Length property of the `furColor` field in the following line will throw a NullReferenceException.

```
while (furColor.Length > 10);
```

One way that you can get around this exception, is by setting default values to those fields in your parameterless constructor, like so:

```
public Dog() : this("brown", "Fido", default(int))
{
}
```

Alternatively, you can:

- Use the constructor with parameters, passing in a non-null value for `furColor`.
- Check against null in the `FurColor` property setter.
- Set the `field` where it is declared.

Answer (score 1):

Your `furColor` variable needs to be assigned and/or checked against null before accessing its length. Since you are using the default constructor, you never assign to the furColor string.
You'll want to call your other constructor from the default:

```
public Dog() : this("defaultColor", "defaultName", default(int)) {}
```

That being said, it isn't good programming practice to ask for user input within a property, **and** you'll end up with an infinite loop with-in your property.